# why is my value not resetting after game ends

Tags: c#, class, visual-studio-2012, operators

My code is for a guessing game, user guesses a number between 1-100. They have 10 tries, after each guess it tells them if its too low or too high, etc.

A problem I'm having that I can't seem to fix is that after they won it tells them they won and how many guesses it took them to win (using `guesses` variable). My problem is that if they win, and they play again, the guesses doesn't reset. So if it takes them 5 tries on the first game, and 8 tries on the second game, in the second game it will tell them they won in 13 guesses (5 from first + 8 from second).

I know why it's happening, but everything I try doesn't seem to fix it. I assumed if i just did something like `guesses = 0;` in the same spot I do `attemptsLeft = 10;` that it would work since the `attemptsLeft` is working fine, but then it just always says they won and it took them 0 guesses. I also tried setting `guesses = 0;` inside the `if` statements for when they win/lose but it does the same thing and says they won in 0 guesses.

### Code for GuessingGame class

```
namespace NumberGuessingGame
{
    public class GuessingGame
    {

        int myGuess = 0;
        int guessesLeft = 10;
        public int gamesPlayed = 0;
        public int gamesWon = 0;
        public int gamesLost = 0;
        public int attemptsLeft = 10;
        public int guesses = 0;

        Random rand;
        int number = 0;

        public GuessingGame()
        {           
            attemptsLeft = 10;
            rand = new Random();
            number = rand.Next(1, 100);            
        }
        public void ResetGame()
        {            
            attemptsLeft = 10;
            number = rand.Next(1, 100);
            guessesLeft = 10;            
        }                
        public int CheckGuess(int newGuess)
        {
            myGuess = newGuess;

            if (guessesLeft < 1)
            {               
                gamesLost++;
                gamesPlayed++;
                ResetGame();                
                return 2;                
            }
            else if (myGuess > number)
            {
                attemptsLeft--;
                guesses++;
                guessesLeft--;
                return 1;
            }
            else if (myGuess < number)
            {                               
                attemptsLeft--;
                guesses++;
                guessesLeft--;
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {               
                guesses++;
                gamesWon++;
                gamesPlayed++;
                ResetGame();                
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Code for form class

```
namespace NumberGuessingGame
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
        }        

        GuessingGame myGuess = new GuessingGame();

        private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int inputGuess = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuess.Text);
            int result = myGuess.CheckGuess(inputGuess);                                           

            if(result == 2)
            {
                lblLosses.Text = "Losses: " + myGuess.gamesLost;
                lblPlayed.Text = "Games Played: " + myGuess.gamesPlayed;
                lblWins.Text = "Wins: " + myGuess.gamesWon;                                       
                MessageBox.Show("You ran out of guesses and lost!");                
            }
            else if(result == 1)
            {               
                MessageBox.Show("Your guess was too high, try again!" + "\n You have " + myGuess.attemptsLeft + " guesses left");
            }
            else if(result == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your guess was too low, try again!" + "\n You have " + myGuess.attemptsLeft + " guesses left");
            }
            else if(result == 0)
            {                
                MessageBox.Show("You won!" + "\n It took you " + myGuess.guesses + " guesses");                
                lblLosses.Text = "Losses: " + myGuess.gamesLost;
                lblPlayed.Text = "Games Played: " + myGuess.gamesPlayed;
                lblWins.Text = "Wins: " + myGuess.gamesWon;    
            }                       
        }
```

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger - focus on the value of `guesses` through the `ResetGame()` method.

Comment: You're also mixing up your concerns - conceptually you've got `GuessingGame` representing both a game play session and a single round of the game - think about splitting those concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'm kind of confused why you increment both number of guesses and attempts left. Can't you just use the logic from either to accomplish the flow of the game instead of keeping track of 2 things that essentially mean the same thing? When you re-play the game see what each variable equates too, are you properly resetting each variable and calling that function? Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I got rid of the guesses increment and just did `guesses = 10 - attemptsLeft;`

Answer (score 0):

You're never resetting the `guesses` value, so of course it keeps incrementing.  You want to retain the guess count after the final guess of any round so that you can display it, then reset it at the start of the next round.

Currently none of your code tracks the status of a round, so that's something to fix.  Also you're using two different variables to track the number of guesses made and remaining, which is excessive.  We can cut that back to a single variable for tracking guesses made which gets reset at the start of a round.

So, start with game state.  We can pack down a few items into the state like this:

```
public enum EGameState
{
    None,
    Playing,
    Won,
    Lost
}
```

The `None` state will be used for the first round, and never thereafter.  While playing a round the state will be `Playing` and at the end of the round either `Won` or `Loss` to indicate outcome.

Now your `GuessingGame` class can be modified to use the state to determine how to react to guesses, etc.  If the game state isn't set to `Playing` then you need to re-initialize the round variables.