# new to programing trying to make a number guessing game in c#

Tags: c#, random

Hi so I am new to programing I just started school and I wanted to get a head start on programing so please keep in mind that everything I show you is all self-taught. Here is my question I wanted to make a random number guessing game and for the most part it works but every time you click the button to guess it randoms a different number which I don’t want here is what I have so far

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // number of guesses
    int numberOfGesses = 0;

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // make the generator
        Random generator = new Random();

        //make the number
        int number = generator.Next(1, 10);


        // get the users guess
        int guess = int.Parse(txtInput.Text);

        //check the users guess
        if (guess == number)
        {
            lblAnswer.Text = "You got it";
            numberOfGesses = 0;
        }
        else if (guess != number)
        {
            numberOfGesses = numberOfGesses + 1;
            lblAnswer.Text = "try agian you have gessed" + (numberOfGesses) + " times";
        }

    }


}
```

I know it keeps creating a new number because every time I press the guess button it starts from the top and makes a new number. I tried to take this block and make it global but I got an error

```
// make the generator
        Random generator = new Random();

        //make the number
        int number = generator.Next(1, 10);
```

again im realy new and i found this site when lookinging up some qeustions i had so i thought it would be a good place to help me learn about programing while i wait till i can get into the programing classes thank you for your time.

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property Form1.generator

Comment: Have a look on the [Guessing Game](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32707303/3796048) Hope this will give you the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely got an error because C# doesn't allow you to assign a default value of a field based on another field.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    int numberOfGuess = 0;
    Random generator = new Random();
    int number;

    // other methods
}
```

`generator` can be initialized before or after `number`, hence the error. Instead, you can put it in the form intializer (`Form1` method), or make another button and click it and generate a new random number:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // number of guesses
    int numberOfGesses = 0;
    Random generator = new Random();
    int number;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Generate the random number
        number = generator.Next(1, 10);
    }

    private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Generate a new random number when you click a button on the form
        number = generator.Next(1, 10);
    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get the users guess
        int guess = int.Parse(txtInput.Text);

        //check the users guess
        if (guess == number)
        {
            lblAnswer.Text = "You got it";
            numberOfGesses = 0;
        }
        else if (guess != number)
        {
            numberOfGesses = numberOfGesses + 1;
            lblAnswer.Text = "try agian you have gessed" + (numberOfGesses) + " times";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked I just want to make sure i understand this does the initialize component block just what the program does before it boots the user interface?

Comment: also when i mouse over the initialize component it says it is required method for designer support and i should not modify it. but didnt i just modify the code?

Comment: The `Form1` method is invoked when the form starts. It's called the initializer or the constructor. `InitializeComponent` set up the controls on your form. Best to leave it alone. If you want more detail, read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297079/very-simple-definition-of-initializecomponent-method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an instance variable to initialize another instance variable. **Why**? Because the compiler can rearrange these - there is no guarantee that generator will be initialized before number, so the above line might throw a `NullReferenceException`.
So change the default number value to 0:

```
Random generator = new Random();
int number = 0;
```

Initialise in the constructor:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        number = generator.Next(1, 10);
    }
```

When the button is clicked generate the number since here you will be needing it:

```
 private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                //take the input & Compare as before.
    }
```

Comment: Does this give the OP the same problem? He wanted to *avoid* generating a new number every time the button is clicked

Comment: sorry if this is a basic question but what is the constructor again im new so   if you could explain what that is it would be helpful thx

Comment: @MatthewSchutten Form1() is the constructor.